# Beamer: transparency of a picture on section frame depending of section number

Tags: beamer, sectioning, counters, framed, transparency

I'm a new Beamer user.
The following code is there just to explain what I intent to do:
Put on the "sectionpage" frames a picture with transparency, the transparency level being function of the sectionnumber.    In the example below, I would like the transparency level (instead of 0.4) to be equal to 0.125 time the current section number. (0.125 for first section, 0.25 for second section and so on).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{default}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme[hideothersubsections]{Goettingen}
 \definecolor{fondtitre}{rgb}{0.83,0.03,0.03}  % dark red
 \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading]%
                   [top=fondtitre!05,bottom=fondtitre!60]
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcounter{totototo}
\AtBeginSection[] %
{
\begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
     Section  \insertsectionnumber\par%
    {\transparent{0.4}\includegraphics[height=2cm]{picture}}
    {\transparent{\thetotototo}\includegraphics[height=2cm]{picture}}%
    {\transparent{\thesection}\includegraphics[height=2cm]{picture}}

  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}  
    \stepcounter{totototo}
      }


\begin{document}
\section{Firstsection}
\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}
\section{Secondsection}
\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}
\section{Thirdsection}
\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

a)This requires multiplication of a counter by a real.

b) If the range of the values for transparency had been 0-100, one could perhaps use another counter set to `12.5*\thesection`. The truncature error beeing insignificant.
As the range is 0-1, we cannot use a counter to store the value.
The totototo test shows that the image is totaly transparent when the counter value is 0 and totally visible when it is upper.

c) would it be possible by modifying the template  (  `\defbeamertemplate*{section page}{default}[1][] )`and doing `\frame{\sectionpage}` in the `AtBegin...`?

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your example is not complete

Comment: Not complete because I don't know how to define the real object to make the multiplication. Should I use \newcommand{\mytransparency}{0.125} or directly use \real.

Comment: I have read about multiplication of counters and dimen but I cannot manage with real or float

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `transparent` you can also use `TiKZ` opacity. Following complete example shows how to use it supposing that every image will show a different opacity.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage{default}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme[hideothersubsections]{Goettingen}
 \definecolor{fondtitre}{rgb}{0.83,0.03,0.03}  % dark red
 \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading]%
                   [top=fondtitre!05,bottom=fondtitre!60]
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcounter{totototo}
\setcounter{totototo}{1}
\AtBeginSection[] %
{
\begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
     Section  \insertsectionnumber\par%
    {\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=0pt, opacity=0.2*\thesection](a){\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}};%
    \node[inner sep=0pt, opacity=0.3*\thetotototo, right=0pt of a](b){\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}};               
    \node[inner sep=0pt, opacity=0.25*\thesection, right=0pt of b](c){\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}  
    \stepcounter{totototo}
      }


\begin{document}
\section{Firstsection}
\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}
\section{Secondsection}
\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}
\section{Thirdsection}
\begin{frame}{}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If all three images use same opacity, the code can be simplified to:

```
    {\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=0pt, opacity=0.2*\thesection]{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a}\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
```

and `positioning` library won't be necessary.